# Custom facets using Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet, elasticsearch-aggregation, faceted-search

I have a search page that uses facets. When a user enters terms in the search bar or selects a facet checkbox on the left hand column, this triggers a new search in our Elastic Search index.
[image]

Here is how the facets work. Our query includes an aggregation on each of the facet categories. For example, the aggregation response for the firstname category includes all first names from the result set and the number of times each name appears in the result set. As this is a Vuejs app and the facet data is a responsive variable, the facet then updates with the new list of keys and document counts in parenthesis.

[image]

This is problematic, because a user can only select a single checkbox in each facet. As soon as the user selects a checkbox, the other options disappear because the new result set and aggregation response now are restricted to documents that satisfy the selected checkbox.

I think what I need to do is customize my aggregation, but I can be wrong and there is a simpler or smarter approach. Let me know if that is the case.

I imagine I need to refactor so that when a user selects a checkbox in category foo, the aggregation operates on a different result set that takes into account the search bar term and the checked values in all other categories, but ignores the user's selections in the foo category. How can this be done in Elastic?

A requirement is that selecting a checkbox immediately triggers a new search to update the table and the content of the other facet categories.

Ultimately, I need to implement this with Elastic's high level REST client for JAVA, but even just cURL examples would be helpful.

Here is my current aggregation query...

```
        for (String colName : colNames) {
        sourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms(colName)
                .field(colName + ".keyword"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, you want your terms aggregation to be independent of search query.

You can use [global aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) for it.

> Defines a single bucket of all the documents within the search
>   execution context. This context is defined by the indices and the
>   document types you’re searching on, but is not influenced by the
>   search query itself

Example

Mapping:

```
{
  "index50" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Data:

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index50",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "v8MR3XABAqtoal9HOsoo",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "john"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index50",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "wMMR3XABAqtoal9HU8rs",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doe"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "john"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "name_global_faucet": {
      "global": {},--> will return terms from all documents
      "aggs": {
        "first_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "name_faucet": {
      "terms": {--> will return terms from documents returned in query
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931472,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index50",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "v8MR3XABAqtoal9HOsoo",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "john"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "name_faucet" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "john",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "name_global_faucet" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "first_name" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "doe",
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          {
            "key" : "john",
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Almost what I want to do. I’d like the selections in all other facets aside from the facet containing the checkbox most recently toggled to be a part of the aggregation.

Comment: @GNG I have updated answer to include 2 aggregations, one global which will return 2 users john and doe, second aggregation will return john (as per filtered documents). you can use keyword "global"  on parent aggregation which you want to be independent of filter context

Comment: Specifically, what we want to do is build our facets to work just like Amazon's.  For example, notice how selecting "Saucony" under the Brands facet updates the Seller facet options accoringly, but the Brands facet options do not change. https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shirt&i=fashion&bbn=7141123011&rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A14630392011%2Cp_n_shipping_option-bin%3A3242350011%2Cp_36%3A2661612011%2Cp_89%3ASaucony&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1584382810&rnid=2528832011&ref=sr_nr_p_89_2

Comment: Do I need to run two searches (one returns all documents filtered by the selections in all facets; the other returns all documents filtered by the selections in all facets EXCEPT for the recently updated facet)? Then one aggregation would aggregate the results from the first search; this would bring back the data needed to update the other facets. The second aggregation would aggregate the results from the second search; this aggregation would bring back the data needed to update the recently updated facet. What is the cleanest way to execute this in Elastic?

Comment: Maybe a multisearch is the best approach?

Comment: I got this working with a multisearch as outlined in my comment above.

Comment: I think can be done in single search. Client side needs to keep rack of last updated faucet and should not bind it with aggregation result returned from search